# Unexpected non-void return value in void function error, but the function is set to return a value

Tags: swift

I have this method which reads data from Firebase.
However, when I want it to return a dictionary so I can use what I got from the Firebase, I get this problem:

```
"Unexpected non-void return value in void function"
```

which I don't understand because I do returning a dictionary (`player`)
and I set the function to return a dictionary.
this is the function:

```
func ReadTeamPlayers(teamName name: String) -> [String:Any]{
    ref.child(name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let player = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
        return player
    }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing your closure with your function. A closure is a essentially a function within another function. Your return is a return in the closure to the `observeSingleEvent()` function. You can't do that. You will need to rewrite your `readTeamPlayers()` function to take a closure, and all that closure once your call to `observeSingleEvent()` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand my mistake now.